# Is it possible to read data from Azure Data base table and write it to Azure Data Lake file with Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-lake

I am trying to implement a time trigger function, which connects to Azure DB and get the contents from table. After this I'm looking out for the possibilities to write this data to a Azure Data lake file using BCP. Below is my function and Json Script

```
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"
#r "System.IO"
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqldb_connection"].ConnectionString;
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
    conn.Open();
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "bcp";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"select * from Person \""+ "queryout 'DatalakeFilepath' -S test-server.database.windows.net -U username -P password  -d database -N";
    proc.Start();
    }
}


//Json:
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

2017-06-19T11:29:31.957 Exception while executing function: Functions.OcDataTimerTriggerCSharp. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. System: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: It is possible. Please elaborate on which exact problem you are facing and what you did to solve it so far. Otherwise, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

(Azure Data Lake team here)

Writing to Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) from an Azure Function is possible - but not in the way you you are doing it in the code above.

You can't write to the ADLS filesystem as if it is a local drive or fileshare. So, calling BCP with a destination path in an ADLS account will not work.

There are a couple of options for you. An Azure Function could:

- Run an ADF pipeline
- Start a U-SQL job to read from the Azure SQL and write to ADLS.
- Manually read from the SQL DB row-by -row and write the rows into ADLS